# How can I EFCore DB Context in an N-Tier architecture with an ASP.NET Core application?

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, .net-core, entity-framework-core, n-tier-architecture

I've been trying to follow an asp.net mvc core tutorial online and I noticed that when using entity framework you can enable it in ConfigureServices in the application start up file like so:

```cs
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
{
    services.AddDbContext<MyContext>(cfg => cfg.UseSqlServer());
    services.AddMvc().SetCompatibilityVersion(CompatibilityVersion.Version_2_2);
}
```

but what if I intend to use an n-tier architecture having different projects for the domain and data layers?

[image]

So I wouldn't have a reference to EntityFramework or the DBContext in my API layer as these would be separated by a domain layer?

The only solution that comes to mind is to add the Context to a "Common" project but that doesn't feel like the right thing to do?

How would you guys solve this?

Comment: I added EF to both projects. This is not a bad design in my opinion.

Comment: @EKOlog but where does your dbContext reside?

Comment: @ Prime By Design in my Database project.

Comment: @PrimeByDesign I'm not sure what you mean by domain and data layer seperation because EF IS the data layer, anything else you declare on top is the domain layer, so you only really need one more project.

Comment: @AvinKavish I'm keeping my layers in separate projects so that the domain / data logic can be referenced without needing to specifically talk to the web api. It could be used by other projects.

Comment: Can you give me an example of what goes into the data layer and what goes into domain? https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multitier_architecture#Three-tier_architecture If you read this you will see that Entity Framework Core **IS** the data layer, there is no need for you to write another data layer. Only a domain layer with the entities.

Comment: @AvinKavish I've added a screenshot of the projects in my solution. UI references Domain references Data contains DbContext

Comment: @PrimeByDesign I've elaborated on my answer, hopefully that helps you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This problem is negligible in terms of architecture, but if you are really concerned about separating the  EF dependencies into a separate project then you can just separate the dependency injection layer alltogether into separate project and use reference only to that in multiple other projects.

**EDIT:**
I may not have been elaborate enough on this so here is an example of what I meant. I assume your `Example.Domain` has some repository which references the your EF `YourDbContext`

```
public class YourDomainRepository
{
    private readonly YourDbContext _context;

    public YourDomainRepository(YourDbContext context)
    {
        _context = context;
    }

    ...Other repository methods
}
```

The issue you are describing is that it's not enough to just reference the `Example.Domain` in your `Example.Api` because in order for the DI to work you need to add it to the services and you need to add both `YourDomainRepository` and other services on which it depends (like `YourDbContext`) which in turns what requires you to reference EF libraries.

So the approach I tried to propose is either:

- Option 1 - you create another project for common stuff like DI. That project would house a function like below:

  ```
  public static class YourDomainDIExtensions
  {
      public static void AddDomainDataServices(this IServiceCollection services)
      {
          services.AddDbContext<YourDbContext>(...);
          services.AddTransient<YourDomainRepository>();
      }
  }
  ```
- Option 2 - you don't create a new project and just have the same extension class in your domain project.

Either way this abstracts the EF dependencies from your `Example.API` and in there you will just call:

```
services.AddDomainDataServices();
```

Which effectively is reusable across multiple projects.

Comment: It's not just the dependencies, I want to keep the context in the data layer. The API layer is separated by a domain layer.

Comment: You will keep the DbContext classes and EF dependencies away from API this way, because in your API you will reference only DI layer which will have abstraction like AddMyDataServices(), which in turn encapsulates adding EF stuff.

Comment: I think option 1 is what I need. I'll try it now!

Comment: Option 1 is a good suggestion. I kind of do the same, but each project is responsible for its own dependencies.

Comment: @WilliamXifaras Yeah it really depends how much reusability you need and separation. It’s quite common to do it in separate projects for reusable libs. You can see many examples like Automapper and Automapper.DependencyInjection (I cant remember if AM actually does that but others do for sure)

Comment: yup! it worked! Actually I'm sure I've had t do this before but I'd just completely forgotten! Thank you!

Answer (score 2):

What I am currently doing is creating an extension in my business logic project which has a reference to the data access project that encapsulates EF Core.
The structure is the following:

- API (ASP.NET Core API - references Services)
- Services (Business Logic - References DataAccess)
- DataAccess (EF Core Here)

In my Services project I have an extension like this:

```
public static class AppExtensions
{
    public static IServiceCollection SetUpAppDependencies(this IServiceCollection serviceCollection,
        string connectionString)
    {
        serviceCollection.AddDbContext<MyDbContext>(options => options.UseSqlServer(connectionString));
        return serviceCollection;
    }
}
```

Then in ConfigureServices I do this:

```
// connectionString should come from KeyVault or Configuration
services.SetUpAppDependencies(connectionString);
```

Answer (score 0):

You only need entity framework in the project (i.e., tier) that actually touches the database. Other projects in the solution can add a reference to the project encapsulating entity framework. For example:

[image]

This is a simplistic example, but the Data project has references to EF. The UI project has references to the Data project. In larger projects, I might even have an API project in between the Data and UI tiers. In those cases, the UI project wouldn't reference either the Data or API projects, as it is entirely UI. That is, the UI project wouldn't have controllers, like the simple example does.

Comment: sure but what happens if you have a domain layer separating your data layer from your UI layer?

Comment: And you need to expose DI methods in your Data layer, otherwise it’s not enough to just reference the Data layer because you can’t actually setup DI injection in your UI. This is what I tried to explain with my answer at least.

Comment: @PrimeByDesign The same applies. EF only goes in the data layer (or project). The domain layer would have a reference to the data project. That way, all of the database access stuff is exposed to the domain layer, but "lives" in the data layer.

Comment: @Kevingy Sorry, I understand that the EF Stuff only goes in the data layer and that the domain would reference is sure. That's not my issue.

Comment: @VidmantasBlazevicius Thanks, Do you think I should perhaps have a common layer with the DI stuff in there?

Comment: @VidmantasBlazevicius I'm not sure what you mean by "DI methods" (dependency injection?), but correct, the data project exposes data access "stuff" to the consumer. Typically, that's the context, entities, and if you're using the Unit of Work pattern, the repositories.

Comment: @PrimeByDesign So, what is the issue, then?

Comment: @Kevingy- UI references Domain references Data contains DbContext. I've added an image in my question. The problem is that the UI layer can't see the DbContext in the data layer as it's only referencing Domain.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/194636/discussion-between-prime-by-design-and-kevingy).

Comment: @PrimeByDesign Ah, see, now you've changed the question.

Comment: @PrimeByDesign Yeah exactly what I mean, you can separate the dependency injection methods into a separate layer to achieve what you want. That’s what I tried to explain in my answer. It is not uncommon to do that.